# Mass node_load for Drupal?

Tags: drupal

Is there an easy way to get several noads loaded into an array? I know node_load works for one node, but what if I have a large list of node ids that I want all data of?

Comment: What's the context? Are you trying to load all keyed nodes in a view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there's no way around node_load as it calls all the load hooks for nodeapi. if you go around it you risk to miss some informations. it looks like in drupal7 there will be a function node_load_multiple() but i don't know how it copes with the nodeapi load hook issue.

if you don't care about extra info, you can just select directly from node or node_revision table using db_query.

Comment: Thats exactly what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 0):

In drupal 7, node_load_multiple($nids, $conditions, $reset) accepts an array of nids and returns an array of node objects.  http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/node_load_multiple/7